# Chamar modal por javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Esses são os arquivos referentes ao boot e o js. Os inseri na página Layout

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Meu modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Esse procedimento pode levar alguns minutos. Por favor aguarde!</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Meu javascript

```
function abreModal() {
 $("#myModal").modal({
      show: true
    });
 }
setTimeout(abreModal, 1000);
```

Meu botão para chamar a função Javascript

```
@Html.ActionLink("Criar nova tabela de Markup", "Create", null, new { @class = "btn btn-azul wd-270", @onclick = "startLoading();abreModal();", @id = "novaTabela" })
```

tá dando esse erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
>       at abreModal (Markup:439)

O que está errado?

Comment: Quando for criar uma pergunta, tente detalha-la com informações importantes, sugiro que leia  [como criar uma boa pergunta aqui na comunidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Então você está utilizando o modal do bootstrap correto? Qual versão realmente você está utilizando a do bootstrap? A função deste botão, você somente quer que ela exiba o modal é isto?

Comment: Tente colocar `data-load-url` no seu botão com o `@Html.ActionLink` nela.

Comment: @Miyukii, e como eu uso no javascript isso, ou não precisa

Comment: Seria no HTML mesmo, mas só agora que eu vi que você quer tirar o botão HTML, então meio que ele seria necessário pra usar @pnet

Comment: @pnet Você inseriu o [arquivo JS](https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/#js) referente ao Bootstrap?

Comment: [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas). Me parece ser um bom tópico para que seja lido para evitar pergunats como essa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É tudo uma questão de ler a [documentação](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#via-javascript).

```js
function abreModal() {
  $("#myModal").modal({
    show: true
  });
}

setTimeout(abreModal, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div id="myModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @pnet Então seu exemplo não é um bom exemplo. Faça um [mcve].

Comment: @pnet Mas não tem como reproduzir o problema. Pela resposta eu mostrei que só chamando a função `modal` e passando o objeto o modal abre corretamente. Se isso não funciona para você é porque outra coisa está interferindo.

Comment: @pnet Não, esses são atributos que o Bootstrap considera para fazer o botão abrir o modal sem que você precise escrever o JS. Para testar, é só fazer como eu fiz na resposta: elimine todos os ruídos. Crie um modal simples (eu copiei da própria documentação) e faça a função igual eu fiz. Se não funcionar, edita a pergunta **somente** com esse código. Se funcionar, o problema está em outro lugar e não temos ajudar.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, consegui com esse exemplo. Era a ordem dos scripts na página layout. Mas tem um problema que não consigo resolver. Quando a página entra, já mostra o Modal e deveria apenas no click do botão. Como resolvo isso?

Comment: Lendo o código que você copiou e colou.

Answer (score -3):

Resolvi dessa forma

```
<input type="hidden" id="md" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" />
```

Função javascript

```
function MostraModal() {
        $("#md").click();
    }
```

E o botão

```
@Html.ActionLink("Criar nova tabela de Markup", "Create", null, new { @class = "btn btn-azul wd-270", @onclick = "startLoading();MostraModal();", @id = "novaTabela" })
```

Sei lá, acho que pode ter outra solução sem a necessidade do `hidden` e ainda fico no aguardo dessa solução, que ao meu entender, seria mais elegante.

Comment: Considerando seu [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/382685/chamar-modal-por-javascript#comment756990_382691), apenas ocultar o botão não parece-me uma solução plausível.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, concordo com você, por isso não dei por encerrada a questão e ainda procuro uma outra solução, sem a necessidade de um hidden. Você está cheio de razão